# Windows 7 can't login from lock screen - says invalid password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login

for the last couple of weeks if I lock my pc with windows key + L, when I try to login I get 'Invalid user or password', then I click on change user, then I can login with my password.

If I try to change my password I also get the invalid password message.

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Post a screenshot of your users.  You can black out their names if you want although thats sort of pointless.

Comment: Ya what Ramhound said, sounds like maybe you have multiple usernames that you log into.  Maybe the default one auto starts with windows or something (may even have no password, try logging in without a password next time you lock your screen).  Also, your caps lock could be on but I doubt that's it given that you're able to log in when you use the switch users option.

Comment: I have 4 users on my pc. I tried without a password and same message.